# Can't uncompress archive with maven 3

Tags: maven-3

I downloaded maven 3 archive on my ubuntu system but can't unpack it. Did anybody know how to resolve this?

I get this error:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

---

P.S. I tried both archives (.tar.gz and .zip) but the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the checksum? Did you test it with your archive?

Run `md5sum apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.tar.gz` and compare the result with the checksum on the Maven download-site (507828d328eb3735103c0492443ef0f0)

Maybe your archive was corrupted.

Comment: The problem was that I downloaded not `maven` archive but [this](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz) `html` page since I believed the fact it ends with `tar.gz` is sufficient for downloading the archive. Dumb from me.

Answer (score 0):

Find and install Gnu Tar and use that. The maven assembly plugin creates tar files that are incompatible with some OS default implementations.